# IE11 on Windows 10 - "always on top" cannot be applied to a child window

Tags: windows, activex, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, always-on-top

We’re developing an ActiveX that runs on IE11.

When running IE11 On Windows 10 with IE’s “protected mode” enabled, a child window cannot be set as “always on top”. Our code that sets “always on top” for the child window looks like this:
::SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
This commands fails with error-code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

I should note the following:

1. This happens even when the website is included in the “trusted sites”
2. This code works perfectly on Windows versions < 10 (with IE's "protected mode" enabled)
3. The main IE11 window can be set to “always on top”, but the child window cannot
4. We've tried to change the settings under Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level..., but nothing helps

Two solutions that are not acceptable by our customer are:

1. Run IE11 elevated (i.e. as Administrator)
2. Disable IE's "protected mode" (Internet Options -> Security -> “Enable protected mode”)

Would like to hear if anyone encountered it, or managed to solve it.

Comment: Alternate ideas for win10: can you use split window and put your app window in 1/3rd of the display? Move and resize other windows so yours is not covered?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that simple, both main window and child window need more than 1/3rd of the display to show correctly